# Rest Call That Throws An Exception -- Firefox/Chrome See Internal Server Error, IE sees Bad Request

Tags: java, ajax, rest, internal-server-error, bad-request

Printing the jqXHR object upon receiving it after a $.ajax call using jQuery 1.6.4 we're seeing a difference in value.

Firefox/Chrome see 500 internal server error along with resposneText containing a stacktrace (on purpose atm for that stacktrace).

IE simply has nothing for responseText and "400" for error type.

**Chrome/FF**

```
!!!!!!RAW Error -> {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"message\":\"Activities in this presentation mode can not contain checkpoints.\",\"code\":\"unknown (class com.ilrn.util.shared.ILrnException)\",\"type\":\"fatal-

etc etc then ends with

net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)\\norg.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)\\njava.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)\"}","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

**IE**

```
RAW Error ->{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":400,"statusText":"failed"}
```

Thanks delightful SO denizens! :D

Comment: Rad. SO minimizes the iamges. :\